# VS2008 C++ /CLI generated code formatting/placement issues

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

New to VS2008...

I am using CLR Forms to create a GUI.  I put a button on the form and then ask the IDE to create a click event.   VS2008 puts the code in the .h file and formats it 'badly' compared to our in-house guidelines.

How do i get the code into the .cpp file and format it correctly?

Worse, when I 'reset' the event, VS2008 does not remove the generated code if I did any edits in it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The managed code tools are mainly written for managed languages and in managed languages there is no header file so everything is in the source file. To port it to C++ it would be easier to just change file extension than to write the code to split generated code into header files and source files

Try the Edit.FormatDocument command (default shortcut CTRL + K, CTRL + D). The modification is **limited** by the settings specified on the Formatting pane of the C++ language in the Text Editor section of the Options dialog box. You can also use Edit.FormatSelection
(ALT + F8 CTRL + K, CTRL + F) after selecting what you want to format. ActiveDocument.Selection.SmartFormat may work too, but I don't know its shortcut. You can create a macro/addin to call it.

There are other tools that can provides better control in formating the current file and some can be even used as external tools or add-ins in Visual Studio. **Search "code beautifier visual C++" or "code formatting visual C++" in your favorite search engine to find them.**

Comment: Edit.FormatDocument does not change the formatting. The formatting options in the C++ editor option dialog are very limited.

Is it standard for the IDE to put code into the .h?

Comment: Code beautification is only half the answer.  VS2008 also puts the code into the .h file, not the .cpp file.  Which is maybe a great idea for C#, but not for C++.  Thanks though!